# grepping output of ps, exclude the word grep

Tags: linux, shell, grep, ps

I'm using ps to find the pid of a process created to execute the command "sleep 1234 &"
I grep the result to match only "sleep 1234".

```
ps -A -f | grep "sleep 1234"
```

however, this matches also the command "grep sleep 1234" itself, returning two lines instead of one. How do I write a pattern for grep to exclude the word 'grep' itself?

Thanks

Comment: ps -A -f | grep "sleep 1234"|grep -v grep

Comment: @AndreGelinas the extra grep here is unnecessary, you just need to make the pattern one that doesn't match itself. See my answer for more details.

Comment: `pgrep -f 'sleep 1234'`

Comment: @MatthewStory Understood and noted (nice trick by the way, ILT) but when using a variable for the first grep (not knowing necessarily the value beforehand) ... I find it easier to do the second grep than to do string manipulation to add the []...unless I've misunderstood something.

Comment: @AndreGelinas with a variable it is harder, but OP is using a literal.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a pretty common problem and the easiest solution is to just surround a character in the grep'ed pattern with square brackets:

```
ps -A -f | grep "[s]leep 1234"
```

This will now match `sleep 1234`, but not `[s]leep 1234` (because of the literal `]` between `s` and `l`), and the grep line no longer matches.

The reason that the `grep` is in the process list is that pipelines are executed from right to left, so the `grep` is actually executed prior to the `ps`.

Comment: Why does this not work? `ps -ef | grep -G "(?:(?!grep).)*(sleep 1234).*$"`  When this is executed in bash I get the following output: `ps -ef | grep -G "(?:(?grep --help).)*(sleep 1234).*"`.