# Bash PCRE regex negative lookbehind anywhere in the line

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep, pcre

I am running this script `docker-maintenance-script.sh`. I want to check if the same clone(s) of program(my script) is running on machine. So I am running a `ps` command inside the script which greps again `docker-maintenance-script.sh`.

```
ps -ef | grep -P "(?<!(grep))(docker\-maintenance\-script\.sh)"
```

output while running the script was:

```
dxadmin   4497  5231  0 22:32 pts/0    00:00:00 bash -x docker-maintenance-script.sh
```

which is only infact this current proceess that is greping.

**So to the problem** -

**I want to discard that entry as that is invoker process. I need ps list that only lists other `docker-maintenance-script.sh` process. not this process.
I need a ps list that discards my current parent pid based on negative look behind usinf pid.**

I tried this

```
ps -ef | grep -P "(?<!(grep))(?<!($$))(docker\-maintenance\-script\.sh)"
```

(`$$` returns current pid of process)
in this case 4497. But that is not helping as it 'not match' only  when its just right before
(docker-maintenance-script.sh). I want to not match the string whenever
`$$` appears anywhere before (docker-maintenance-script.sh). Please Help

I tried too `ps -ef | grep -P "(?<!($$.*))(docker\-maintenance\-script\.sh)"`
but that returns non-fixed length lookbehind grep error

Comment: Try `"^(?!.*$$).*docker-maintenance-script\.sh"`

Comment: @anubhava how will that work, can please explain I'm curious

Comment: It is explained in dup question, please check.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much. That kind of works. But your regex "not matches" line if $$ is anywhere in the line. I am wondering how would I do if I really wanted to discard only if $$ were before "docker-maintenance-script\.sh"?

Comment: Simple, `"^(?!.*$$.*docker-maintenance-script\.sh).*docker-maintenance-script\.sh"`. But doesn't https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51178976/grepping-output-of-ps-exclude-the-word-grep work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you! In reply-you guys didn't get it, excluding grep is not my issue, excluding my current parent process (the current running script) was my problem